# Centering my menu

Tags: css

I am have made a menu and now I am trying to centering it.

I am doing this by giving the class `.navigation ul` a `display:block` and then doing `margin:0 auto`.

For some reason this is not working.

You can find a live example here https://jsfiddle.net/fu7uore0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just easy. added `display: flex` for .navigation

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/*Navigation section*/

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navigation li img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}
/*The slider*/

.slick-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh!important;
}
.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>About me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://phoenixsociety.com/img/phoenix-logo-k.png">
      </li>
      <li><a>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>About me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--  <div class ="logo"><img src="http://phoenixsociety.com/img/phoenix-logo-k.png"></div> -->

  <!-- Bootstrap js -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- custom js -->
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but i mean center the menu from the left. the entire menu is aligned left now, i want this in the middle.

Comment: @Kevin.a ok. i change my answer. use `display: flex` for `.navigation`

Comment: The purpose of a `display: flex` is not what the OP intends to achieve here. Its like hitting a candy with a hammer. A simple `text-align` should do the job. :)

Comment: @nashcheez the goal is to work, and with a hammer or a scalpel, this is the tenth question. :P

Answer (score 0):

You should give a `text-align: center;` to `.navigation ul` to center the child elements.

Refer code:

```css
/*Navigation section*/

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation li img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}
/*The slider*/

.slick-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh!important;
}
.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>About me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://phoenixsociety.com/img/phoenix-logo-k.png">
      </li>
      <li><a>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>About me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--  <div class ="logo"><img src="http://phoenixsociety.com/img/phoenix-logo-k.png"></div> -->

  <!-- Bootstrap js -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- custom js -->
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
```